# How do you keep call centre operators updated if your application makes frequent changes?

Tags: release, release-management

Our company is trying to deploy faster, but finding it difficult updating our support staff, i.e. Call centre operators.

We are finding it hard to update 1000+ operators using video or visual media... common problems include 'video fatigue' or operators simply not reviewing material.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't have a definite answer to this, however it would be worth looking at companies e.g. Netflix who do constant updates to systems with huge user bases. They don't tend to push the new features in the traditional sense of big announcements but with subtle in app hints.